# Value of $b$ in smallest triplet of perfect squares $(a,b,c)$ where $a+5k=b, b+5k=c.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, square-numbers

> Find the value of $b$ in the smallest triplet of perfect squares $(a,b,c)$ such that $a+5k=b$ and $b+5k=c$ for positive integers $a,b,c,k.$

I started by defining $a=a_1^2, b=b_1^2, c=c_1^2$ for convenience as they are perfect squares. Then, we know that $$a_1^2=a_1^2, \;(a_1^2+5k)=b_1^2, \;(a_1^2+10k)=c_1^2.$$ I'm not completely sure on how to continue from here, but I assume we have to solve the equaions in the problem and then try to minimize $b$ from there. May I have some help? Thanks in advance.

When I say smallest triplet, I mean a triplet that has its value of $b$ as minimal as possible.

Comment: $b_1=3,a_1=2,c_1=8$

Comment: I don't believe this triplet works either, as $a,b,c$ are all not perfect squares.

Comment: I found a triplet $(25, 625, 1225)$ but how do I prove it is minimal?

Comment: Remember $$a=a_1^2=?\cdots$$

Comment: I know $a_1^2=b_1^2-5k=c_1^2-10k$ but I don't see how this helps...

Comment: (25,625,1225) is not minimal (A smaller triplet was found via code, I have not solved the problem.)

Comment: Oh, interesting, thanks for sharing!

Comment: Something to think about, though: The difference between any two perfect squares is the sum of consecutive odd integers. Not sure if that will help, it may be dead-end logic.

Comment: Oh thanks for the information. I'll try to expand on that idea.

Comment: From $c_1^2-a_1^2=(c_1-a_1)(c_1+a_1)=10k$, we get that $5$ must divide $c_1-a_1$ or $c_1+a_1$ by Euclid's lemma. Note also that $a_1$ and $c_1$ must have the same parity since $a_1^2+c_1^2=2b_1^2$ is even, so in fact $10$ divides $c_1-a_1$ or $c_1+a_1$. Oscar's example gives $c_1-a_1=10$ with $a_1=7$ and $c_1=17$. Not sure that analysis is all that helpful, though. Since you want to minimize $b$, it's already natural to try small $a_1$ and $c_1$.  Maybe there are some other properties people can find.

Comment: There is a curious relationship between most of the tested quadruples that have the same $k$-value. In each of the pairs of quadruples below, the ratio of square roots of $A_2$ to $A_1$ is $23$.

\begin{align*}(1,841,1681,168)&\quad  (529,1369,2209,168)\\
(4,3364,6724,672)&\quad  (2116,5476,8836,672)\\ 
(9,7569,15129,1512)&\quad  (4761,12321,19881,1512)\\
(16,13456,26896,2688)&\quad  (8464,21904,35344,2688)\\
(25,21025,42025,4200)&\quad  (13225,34225,55225,4200)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would like to have $p^2,q^2,r^2$ in arithmetic progression. So $$p^2+r^2=2q^2$$

Perhaps it is easier to catalog solutions to this Pythagorean-like equation. And then examine them for when there is a common difference that is a positive multiple of $5$.

Cataloging the solutions for these triples can be done in the same way as for Pythagorean triples. I leave out the details since that is a significant detour here. But solutions are

$$p=(u-v)^2-2v^2$$
$$q=u^2+v^2$$
$$r=(u-v)^2-2u^2$$

$\{u,v\}=\{0,j\}\implies(p^2,q^2,r^2)=(j^4,j^4,j^4)$ and differences are $0$.

$\{u,v\}=\{\pm j,\pm j\}\implies(p^2,q^2,r^2)=(4j^4,4j^4,4j^4)$ and differences are $0$.

$\{u,v\}=\{\pm1,\pm2\}\implies(p^2,q^2,r^2)=(1,25,49)$ and differences are $24$.

$\{u,v\}=\{\pm1,\pm3\}\implies(p^2,q^2,r^2)=(4,100,196)$ and differences are $96$.

$\{u,v\}=\{\pm2,\pm3\}\implies(p^2,q^2,r^2)=(49,169,289)$ and differences are $120$, finally a positive multiple of $5$.

And we know this is minimal for $b$ since we are listing these things in increasing order of $\sqrt{b}=u^2+v^2$.

---

A few more:

$\{u,v\}=\{\pm1,\pm4\}\implies(p^2,q^2,r^2)=(49,289,529)$ and differences are $240$, also a positive multiple of $5$. (So a new solution not mentioned yet in comments or answers.)

$\{u,v\}=\{\pm2,\pm4\}\implies(p^2,q^2,r^2)=(16,400,784)$ and differences are $384$.

$\{u,v\}=\{\pm3,\pm4\}\implies(p^2,q^2,r^2)=(289,625,961)$ and differences are $336$.

---

This is only cataloguing *primitive* solutions to that diophantine equation. A full catalog should also explore the non-primitve solutions. Like the solution above $(1,25,49)$, scaled by $25$ to get the original OP observed solution.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by minimal. The triple $25, 625,1225$ has a smaller $a$, but $49,169,289$ beats it for $b$ and $c$.

Comment: I don't speak spanish, but google translate gives $841, 1681, 2401.$ However, this triplet does not work because $2401-1681=720,$ while $1681-841=840.$

Comment: Wow, you find a smaller triple! Yes, this would be considered a smaller triple, by smaller I mean the triple that minimizes $b.$

Comment: In any event I found a different answer with smaller numbers. And yes I should have started with 961.

Comment: @mathisfun brute force can be used against $a,b \in \{1,4,9,\cdots, 144\} ~: ~a < b$ to verify $b = 169$ represents the minimum value for $b$.

Comment: Oh cool! Programming seems to be very powerful sometimes. Thanks for the information. If possible, I would also appreciate a math solution, though I understand it seems to be tricky.

Comment: For minimizing a, (1, 841, 1681) with k=168

Comment: Does anyone mind sharing their program? I'm quite interested to see how it works :)

Comment: @mathisfun Here's mine, I wanted practice with Z3 (a theorem prover) so I decided to use a sledgehammer to kill a fly: https://pastebin.com/VMHnMEeM.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
a+5k&=b \tag{1}\\
b+5k=c \implies c-5k&=b \tag{2}\\
\implies a+c&=2b \tag{3}\\
\implies a=b=c&=1^2 \tag{4}
\end{align*}
This works only if
$\space k = \dfrac{b - a}{5}\space$
and $\sqrt{2b-a}= \big\lfloor\sqrt{2b-a}\space\big\rfloor$
The first solution $(3)\rightarrow 
(4)$  is easy to see if we let $k=\dfrac{1-1}{5}=0\space $
but it is required that $k>0$ so the smallest triple for $a$ is
$(1, 841, 1681) $
where $k=\dfrac{841-1}{5}=168$

The smallest triple for
$b$ and $c$ and $k$ is $(49, 169, 289 )$ where
$k=\dfrac{169-49}{5}=24$

These and other triples may be explored with:

```
 110 print “Enter HI number”; : input h1
 120 print "a","  b",,"  c",,"  k"
 130 for a1 = 1 to h1
 140    for b1 = 1 to h1
 150       k1 = (b1^2-a1^2)/5
 160       if k1 > 0
 170       if k1 = int(k1)
 180         c1 = 2*b1^2-a1^2
 190         if sqr(c1) = int(sqr(c1))
 200           print a1^2, b1^2, c1, k1
 210          endif
 220        endif
 230        endif
 240     next b1
 250  next a1
```